# Warning: Native component for "RNGMapsViewManager" does not exist

Tags: android, git, reactjs, npm, react-native

When using react-native-gmaps package and resolve dependencies it gives this error in the debugger,

Following the installation steps correctly in the react-native-gmaps git repo didn't help
https://github.com/teamrota/react-native-gmaps

Issue #15 has the same question, but no clear answer.

https://github.com/teamrota/react-native-gmaps/issues/15